# How to delay infinite class in animate.css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am using https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ in order to create a css animation. I am currently using the infinite class in order to make it repeat. But I want to however make it repeat every 5 seconds or so instead of every second. Is there a way to do this with CSS or jQuery?

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 name animated infinite zoomIn">
                    <h1>vicki williams</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [in the docs](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css#usage), my friend:

```
#yourElement {
  -vendor-animation-duration: 3s;
  -vendor-animation-delay: 2s;
  -vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: That only delays the first iteration of the animation. From the sounds of it, OP wants the delay to happen with every iteration of the animation, not just the first one.

Comment: Yeah, all of that and more is in the docs. Thanks @MichaelCoker.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you want your animation to repeat every 5 seconds, set the `animation-iteration-count` to `infinite` and set the `animation-duration` to a value that includes however long you want the animation to take, then include the 5 seconds of delay.

For example, in the example below, `animation: color 6s infinite;` sets the animation to take 6s, and in my animation, I fade from black to red up to 17% (1s), then back to back immediately and through the rest of the animation (5s), then it repeats. Which is a way of fading from black to red in 1s, resetting and having a 5s delay, then the animation repeats.

```css
h1 {
  animation: color 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  17% {
    color: red;
  } 
  18% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```